# My localhost doesn't see my html and php files from www on Windows 10 (wamp)

Tags: php, html, wamp

So when I try to access `http://localhost` from Chrome it directs me to WAMPSERVER Homepage and it doesn't show me the html or php files that I have in the www folder. What should I do?

Comment: Make sure that the default index.php file preset inside www folder, If present just see it content is right

Comment: @Ajith And how do I figure it out if it's right or not?

Comment: `http://localhost` is where wamp located on, you need to create a folder in `www` and put all your files in that folder and search like `http://localhost/your_folder/your_file_name.html` or `.php`

Comment: No worries glad to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access anything except `ixdex.html` or `index.php`, you will need to 
provide the absolute path in the url like 
`http://localhost/your_folder/page.php` Or based on `url_patterns` defined in rewriter config.

If you don't specify the page file name then the file with the name index.html is displayed, which is happening right now.